# Чтение вредоносного файла

Tags: c#, .net, файлы, безопасность

Допустим, если использовать `FileStream` для чтения вредоносного файла, то может ли он нанести какой-то вред?

Comment: Никакие файлы не являются вредоносными сами по себе. Вредоносными они становятся, когда их кто-то неправильно обрбатывает. Сам по себе FileStream не делает ничего такого, на что влияло бы содержимое файла, а что будет после FileStream — уже на вашей совести

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не может, но антивирус при наличии, может заблокировать чтение такого файла, будет исключение.

Вредоносы, это обычно исполняемый код. Если его читаете как данные но не запускаете, то заразит ли он вам машину? Никакой магии здесь нет.

Comment: Угу. Только не нужно забывать про переполнение буфера. Ошибки такого типа активно использовались. Помню был такой вирус Sasser, он ко мне сам пришёл по корпоративной сети. То есть  какая-то программа на компьютере вроде бы читает данные, но потом эти данные почему-то исполняются как код (известно, почему). Но высокоуровневых операций типа того, что делает FileStream, это не касается (слава богу!). Нужно ещё иметь ввиду такие вещи, при которых данные вдруг становятся кодом, как SQL-иньекции; программы для интерпретаторов типа Питона, Руби и т. п.; скриптовых платформ в операционных системах и

Comment: браузерах; документы с макросами и прочее. Нужно быть начеку и никогда не нажимать Ввод или дважды щёлкать мышкой на файлах, даже если они не исполняемые. В общем, с данными нужно работать как с данными и не давать к ним доступ никаким исполняющим программам.